# Is there an equivalent function of mysqli_fetch_assoc for ldap

Tags: php, pdf, ldap, tcpdf

I have made a directory that enables the user to search for other users if they are on the Active Directory. I actually use ldap to make this possible. The problem is I want to export the result of the search via TCPDF (https://tcpdf.org/).

If I'm right I have to do the research again and then read my entries but I don't know how to proceed. I saw some example of tcpdf with MySQL db but none with ldap. So I don't have a clue of which function I have to use to read my entries.

Comment: [Check search example](http://www.xwood.net/tools/php/5.x/PHP5_zh_Index/fancy/ref.ldap.html)

Comment: thx i've solved my problem ! The problem wasnt from my ldap_search() function but from the one i used to take the result of ldap_search()